# Troubleshooting FirebaseDatabase

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I am a new Flutter developer. Currently working on accessing data from my FBDB.
I have a call to a function that looks like this.

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future<PartInfo> partInfo = HelperMethods.getPartDeets(widget.partid)
```

}

The HelperMethods has code that looks like this.

```
 class HelperMethods {
  static Future<PartInfo> getPartDeets(String partid) async {
    PartInfo partInfo ;

    DatabaseReference partRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('parts/id0001');
    partRef.get().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.value != null) {
        partInfo = PartInfo.fromSnapshot(snapshot); //globalvar currentUserInfo
        print('part is ${partInfo.partname}');
        return partInfo;
      } else {
        print('snapshot is null') ;
      }
    });

    print(partInfo);
    return partInfo;
  }
}
```

My database has data that looks like this:

[image: Image of my firebasedatabase]

The print statements in the getPartDeets method are not being hit ever. and print(partInfo) returns null. Any tips on how I can fix this?

Comment: Instead of `partRef.get().then..` try `partRef.once().then..`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `await`, given that you've marked the method `async` anyway:

```
  static Future<PartInfo> getPartDeets(String partid) async {
    PartInfo partInfo ;

    DatabaseReference partRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('parts/id0001');
    DataSnapshot snapshot = await partRef.get();
    if (snapshot.value != null) {
      partInfo = PartInfo.fromSnapshot(snapshot); //globalvar currentUserInfo
      print('part is ${partInfo.partname}');
      return partInfo;
    } else {
      print('snapshot is null') ;
    }

    print(partInfo);
    return partInfo;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issues by moving my methods into a Future method where I was `await` results. Also had to add a FutureBuilder to my stack. Comment if you want more info.